# валидация формы на корректность данных

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть форма

```
<?php

$code = 1234;

 ?>

<input type="text" placeholder="Введите код сообщения"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="проверить"  />
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так что бы что когда ввожу 1234, у меня выходило сообщение что код верный, если нет то ошибка.

Все что я нахожу это валидацию формы, заведена форма или нет.

я делаю это так

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" pattern="<?php echo $code ?>" />
    <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
  </form>
```

Как добавить что бы внизу выходило, если верно введено то ниже надпись корректно введено и внизу выходила еще input, а если нет то ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Если Ваш код является секретным (а иначе зачем его хранить в php на сервере?), то решение задачи должно быть следующим:

Вы создаёте отдельный php-файл (скажем, code.php), где будет храниться и по запросу возвращаться Ваш код

```
<?php
    $code = 1234;
    echo $code;
?>
```

В форме добавляете атрибуты action и method и с помощью ajax'a (чтобы не перезагружалась страница) отправляете запрос на сервер, чтобы сравнить Ваш код и код, введённый пользователем. Если значения не совпадают, выводите сообщение об ошибке. Если совпадают, пишете "успешно" и открываете скрытый второй инпут

```
<form action="code.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Введите код сообщения"  />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="проверить"  />
  <p class="message"></p>
  <input type="text" name="newInput" hidden="" placeholder="Скрытый инпут" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[type=submit]').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        const form = $("form");
        $.ajax({
          cashe: false,
          type: form.attr('method'),
          url: form.attr('action'),
          data: form.serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
            if($('[name=code]').val() == data) {
                $('.message').text('Верно!').css('color','green');
                $('[name=newInput]').prop('hidden',false);
            }
            else {
                $('.message').text('Ошибка!').css('color','red');
            }
          }
        }); 
    });
});
```

**Вариант 2**

Если же Ваш код не секретный, то с php вообще нет смысла заморачиваться - вы можете прямо на клиенте проверять то, что ввёл пользователь, и осуществлять дальнейшие действия:

```js
$('[type=submit]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($('[name=code]').val() == 1234) {
    $('.message').text('Верно!').css('color','green');
    $('[name=newInput]').prop('hidden',false);
  }
  else {
    $('.message').text('Ошибка!').css('color','red');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">
  <input type="text" name="code" placeholder="Введите код сообщения"  />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="проверить"  />
  <p class="message"></p>
  <input type="text" name="newInput" hidden="" placeholder="Скрытый инпут" />
</form>
```

Comment: все круто, работает, спасибо огромное
я добавляю класс для инпута то форма сразу выходит открытой, почему так?
class="input-form-control text-center"

Comment: @fermeg, не очень понял - куда именно и что Вы добавляете? напишите здесь

Comment: Функционал такой
форма с номером телефона я нажимаю отправляется на номер телефона код смс, я его вожу если корректно то выходит форма, если нет то ошибка

Comment: @fermeg, и? я просто не очень понимаю, в чём вопрос? лучше всего полностью приведите код в вопросе (а не урывками) и объясните, на каком этапе возникают проблемы

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q6k14o то что когда нажимаю проверить выходит ошибка

Comment: @fermeg без полного Вашего кода я не смогу угадать, почему она возникает

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q6k2p7, https://prnt.sc/q6k3e5

Comment: @fermeg, во-первых, у Вас одна форма вложена в другую - это недопустимо. Во-вторых, у вас type=submit во второй форме с лишней буквой t написан. В-третьих, проверьте, что возвращает ajax (и возвращает ли вообще что-то).

Comment: сделал по другому
https://prnt.sc/q6kfms, https://prnt.sc/q6kgdf

когда убираю ваш код, то смс все корректно отправляется

Comment: @fermeg, ну так Вы зачем-то мой код ajax прикрутили к форме, которая отправляет sms. А мой код - он уже для проверки. Второй код, который без ajax, он вообще не нужен - я его Вам просто в качестве примера привёл (что так можно сделать, если не нужен php)

Comment: Как-то не стыкуется хранение **секретного кода** в файле, который доступен по **прямой ссылке**.

Comment: @humster_spb я сделаю 1 форму, потом открывается другая и в ней происходит проверка

Comment: @fermeg, я понимаю. Я говорю, что мой код - он уже для проверки. А для изначальной отправки sms у Вас должен быть другой обработчик.

Comment: @ humster_spb
https://prnt.sc/q6m8ti
я сделал 1 форму ввода телефона, потом переходит в форму проверку, там работает ваш скрипт, помогите пожалуйста как сделать что бы после ввода имени и нажатии кнопку отправить мне переходило в следующую форму или обращалось аяксом к другой форме, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `'1234'` вставьте свою переменную из php.

```js
let code = 1234; // '<?php echo $code;?>'
let input = document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
  input.value == code ? console.log('success') : console.log('error')
})
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если этот код какой-то типа секретный (а иначе зачем его хранить в php на сервере?), то `let code = <?php echo $code;?>` выведет это значение в браузер, и в любом отладчике можно будет подглядеть.

Comment: @ryzen вы консоли выходит ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Проверьте что такое `input` у вас